# ¿Cuál es la manera más rápida de ordenar una matriz de palabras alfabéticamente en c?

Tags: c

Yo utilizo el método de burbuja pero al ser demasiados elementos este se vuelve lento, espero y alguien conozca una manera mas rápida de hacerlo
Les dejo mi código

```
void Ord_Alfabeticamente(char nombres[][100], int &n)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; k++)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < (n - 1) - k; f++)
        {
            if (strcmp(nombres[f], nombres[f + 1]) > 0)
            {
                strcpy(aux, nombres[f]);
                strcpy(nombres[f], nombres[f + 1]);
                strcpy(nombres[f + 1], aux);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Gracias espero me puedan ayudar!!

Comment: Si el metodo de burbuja es demaciado lento, usa un algorimo mas rapido. `quick sort`, `merge sort`, etc.

Comment: Mira un video de comparación, [aquí](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BeoCbJPuvSE) tienes uno. Sugiero **quick sort** o **radix sort**.

Comment: quick sort es el mas rapido

Comment: Una duda es más rápido el quick sort de manera recursiva o de manera iterativa, ya que lo implemente de manera recursiva pero me tarda más tiempo, incluso más que con el de burbuja.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por cada reordenación estás haciendo tres copias de cadenas:

```
strcpy(aux, nombres[f]);
strcpy(nombres[f], nombres[f + 1]);
strcpy(nombres[f + 1], aux);
```

La copia de cadenas es una operación costosa, y además la haces ¡tres veces!. En lugar de ordenar cadenas, ordena índices:

```
void Ord_Alfabeticamente(char *nombres[], int indices[], int n)
{
    for (int k = 0; k < n - 1; ++k)
    {
        for (int f = 0; f < (n - 1) - k; ++f)
        {
            if (strcmp(nombres[indices[f]], nombres[indices[f + 1]]) > 0)
            {
                int aux = indices[f];
                indices[f] = indices[f + 1];
                indices[f + 1] = aux;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Verás que es notablemente más rápido, puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fVLRTsIwFH1ev@I6Y7LKMKC8DUh8MD7yri6m61ZoYC2WzmjIvn3ergxYIDZZ13vvuaenPeXDJedNcysV31R5AdOdzaV@WM3JecpItXQ58q1lDguTfz5vBMsKKzkrC2WLiK@YgXuly8wUu/c0Bqksfrnkp1BRsieAQ2gDkcusYQajBH9TUDCEcQKDwZq2GI/soYVHC0RHLZzitHY9gh7Rpz43pIAI5fNyG3XaOlEiRVkXSRjAOE0pzGFEe0x93pYbJbHqB0WdKJMrqK52Dmy3@Qfc1rEB@fuomvRXNakJcUpKJlXk7HGXHPTtmDiqffhWZIaFMYQLo6TVBl3l2sUvX5XMVVt6rRhayn51WCckODfRk4xiGMfwGMMT1klw7Skcdo27zhgm1GGPPnqAN/OwvpnBxBnpQ0oCPEOwRYFWROHd7kOFl175GM1CoXgJgSlsZRSSkrpp/gA)</kbd>.